# two JS variables refer to same Json object how to keep one constant?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
    $.getJSON('json.ashx?mode=Gender', function (data) {
            memberInfo = data[1]; 
            options.series = data;
            originalData = data[0];
            ...
            ...
    });
```

which returns

```
[
{"type" : "pie","name" : "Gender",
"data" : [["Male",32],["Female",11]]},
{"A123":"F","A223":"M","A423":"F","A332":"M","B327":"F"}
]
```

and

```
    function calcOptionsData() {   
    ...    
    var maleCount = 0;
    var femaleCount = 0;       
    ...              
    ...
    $.each(val, function(index, item) {
        if (memberInfo[item] == 'M')                    
            maleCount += 1;

        if (memberInfo[item] == 'F')                    
            femaleCount += 1;
    });

    options.series[0].data[0][1] = originalData.data[0][1];
    options.series[0].data[1][1] = originalData.data[1][1];

    if (radioBttnClicked == 'Gender')
    {

        options.series[0].data[0][1] += maleCount;

        options.series[0].data[1][1] += femaleCount;
    }
}
```

I want every times the calcOptionsData() called the originalData resets the options.series[0].data to the value originally generated from the getJSON. The current code mirrors originalData with options.series[0].data.

Thanks,

Comment: It's unclear what your question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `$.extend(true, {}, originalObject)` to create an independent deep copy of a JSON object.

Then you may use this copy for any purpose without affecting the original object.

See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) for more information.

Comment: Its called object literals and not JSON objects http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) to do a deep copy of the json object into another variable.